# syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'"

Tags: syntax, token, unexpected-token

```
if [ $pass = "123456" ] ; then mysql -u root -p$pass "create database newdb"; use newdb; CREAT TABLE user ( name char (30) , lname char (40) );
echo "creat table succesful" fi
```

When I run it it outputs start and then says Syntax error:

> "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

> if [ $pass = "123456" ] ; then mysql -u root -p$pass "create database newdb"; use newdb; CREAT TABLE user ( name char (30) , lname char (40) );
>   echo "creat table succesful"; fi

that is a semicolon before the fi.

Also the entire command sequence to mysql probably has to be in double quotes.